# How to create an array of objects with a for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a array of objects called listData that I would like to call certain information from into a separate called markers.

```
var markers = [];
for(let i=0;i<listData.length;i++){
    markers.push({
        latitude:this.state.listData[i].geometry.location.lat,
        longitude:this.state.listData[i].geometry.location.lng,
        title:this.state.listData[i].name
    });
}
```

but it is not working.

Comment: The variable is listData or this.state.listData? Check the for conditions

Comment: Why do you want to push the state into another object. Can't you just use the state as it is in the render or do you need to pass it down as props to a child component?

Comment: Yes, I was trying to do the latter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like to use "map" for such data returns. Nothing wrong with what others posted, I just like this concise syntax a bit better. I am assuming you are referencing the initially value incorrectly. You didn't use this.state.listData in your loop.

```
var markers = this.state.listData.map(function(v){
    return {
       latitude:v.geometry.location.lat,
       longitude:v.geometry.location.lng,
       title:v.name
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code, I assume that you need something like the following:

```
for( let i=0; i < listData.length; i++ ){
    markers.push(
    {
        latitude: listData[i].geometry.location.lat,
        longitude: listData[i].geometry.location.lng,
        title: listData[i].name
    }
);
```

You just want to loop through `listData` and add for each item of this array (or array like object) a new object to the `markers` array. So I don't get why you used `this.state` to access the `listData`.

Answer (score 0):

**Try** this, i think this is what you want.

Remove `this` and start the hierarchy from `state`, if its not helping you can remove both `this.state` and start afterwords.

```js
var markers = [];

for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
 markers.push(
   {
    latitude:'0123',
    longitude:'0345' 
   });
}

console.log(markers);
```

**Change** and **Add** `values` as you desire for yourself.